# iMessage app prevent selection when swiping between apps

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

I have a UICollectionView with a 'didSelectItemAt indexPath' that seems to be receiving a touchUp gesture when swiping to the next iMessage app.

I tried preventing this in the 'didResignActive' method, but that doesn't get called when transitioning between apps.

Any ideas?